# How to access & recover my encrypted files?

Tags: boot, mount, ecryptfs

I've been having a bunch of issues lately attempting to regain access to my encrypted files/partition after my laptop manufacturer's tech support had me try some monkeying about with updating `initramfs` to resolve some touchpad driver issues,

```
<username>@computer:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.7.1-040701-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: invalid line in /etc/crypttab for sda3_crypt -
```

after which I've no longer been able to boot into the computer, getting various error messages on boot:

[image]

I have a 16.04 live USB key which I've used to access the machine, and have found and attempted to use various guides online for recovering my encryptfs .Private files including https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory among several others, but keep getting stymied one way or another:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: ‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/kernel/debug’.

ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo mount -t encryptfs /media/ubuntu/1a01f688-6cc7-4759-ad25-f9366ee275f8/home/.ecryptfs/<username>/.Private /home/<username>/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'encryptfs'

ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo ecryptfs-mount-private /media/ubuntu/1a01f688-6cc7-4759-ad25-f9366ee275f8/home/.ecryptfs/<username>/.Private/
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly
```

I'm at my wits-end and would very much appreciate any and all the help I could please get to resolve this! I'm totally OK if we can fix the booting and leave the encrypted files as-is (assuming they're normally) accessible afterwards, or please help me recover my files via my Live USB boot and then I'll just wipe and re-install everything from scratch.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50497/discussion-on-question-by-croudsourcedninja-how-to-access-recover-my-encrypted).